# How can I end the process of one extension through another extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

There is an extension installed by the administrator on my chromebook, so I can not delete it. When I go to task manager I can find the extension and when I click "end process", the extension stops for about 5 seconds. Then it re-opens itself.

What I am trying to do is make an extension that will automatically end the process of the extension that is installed by my administrator every 5 seconds (5000 ms). Is this possible using just JavaScript, Css, and HTML ?

Comment: That sounds like a problem you shouldn't even be attempting to try and solve in the first place.

Comment: The extension blocks many useful sites usch as: stack exchange, stack overflow (when im in the building)... And even some sites that the teacher needs for class.